# Expectation of a Sum

Tags: probability-or-statistics, evaluation

I'm using `Expectation` to calculate the Gaussian integral of a user-supplied function.  The following works well and fast (< 1 second):

```
a[xi_, xj_] := E^(-1/2*(xi - xj)^2/σa^2);

Expectation[a[x[i], x[j]], x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]]
```

[image]

If I try it on an indefinite `Sum`, it takes 165 seconds to ultimately fail:

```
Expectation[
  Sum[a[x[i], x[j]], {j, n}, Method -> "Procedural"],
  x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]
]
```

[image]

Manually switching the order to a `Sum` of the `Expectation` works great (again, < 1 sec):

```
Sum[
  Expectation[a[x[i], x[j]], x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]],
  {j, n}, Method -> "Procedural"
]
```

[image]

However, all this is happening inside another function that takes arbitrary input (including the `Sum`), so I want to switch the `Sum` and `Expectation` automatically.  The following replacement rule does the trick, but is very slow (165 seconds):

```
Expectation[
  Sum[a[x[i], x[j]], {j, n}, Method -> "Procedural"],
  x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]
] /. Expectation[Sum[func_, range_, opts___], dist_] :> Sum[Expectation[func, dist], range, opts]
```

[image]

Is there a better (faster, more elegant) way to achieve the same output?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the notation.  If `x[i]` is a random variable, then isn't `x[j]` also a random variable?  If so, the distribution of `x[j]` seems to be ignored.  Also, because the sum over `j` includes `i`, the case of`a[x[i],x[i]]` occurs.  The value of `Expectation[a[x[i], x[i]], x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], \[Sigma][i]]]` becomes 1 which is not the general form that you show.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, which helped me realize that I set up my toy example wrong (should be the `x[j]` that are distributed not the `x[i]`). The problem still exists, but I'll need to put the `Expectation`s inside the `Sum` earlier, so maybe not relevant to me anymore.

Comment: The problem comes from ecological models with intraspecific trait variation. The `x[i]` and `x[j]` are the traits of interacting individuals, who compete with competition kernel `a[x[i], x[j]]`. Assuming each species' traits are normally distributed, we have to integrate over their distributions to compute competition.  See [this paper](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1530036/FULLTEXT01.pdf) for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an extended comment.

If all of the `x[i]` are random variables with `NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]`, I wonder if what you really want is the following:

```
a[xi_, xj_] := E^(-1/2*(xi - xj)^2/\[Sigma]a^2);
```

If `i != j`, then we have

```
FullSimplify[Expectation[a[x[i], x[j]], {x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]],
  x[j] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[j], σ[j]]}], 
  Assumptions -> {σa > 0, σ[i] > 0, σ[j] > 0}]
```

[image: Expectation for i and j]

But if `i=j`, then one has

```
FullSimplify[Expectation[a[x[i], x[i]], x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]], 
  Assumptions -> {σa > 0, σ[i] > 0}]

(* 1 *)
```

So you could just define the expectation of `a[xi_, xj_]` as

```
ea[i_, j_] := Piecewise[{{1,i==j}},(E^(-((xav[i] - xav[j])^2/(2 (σa^2 + σ[i]^2 + σ[j]^2)))) σa)/Sqrt[σa^2 + σ[i]^2 + σ[j]^2]]
```

and

```
Sum[ea[i, j], {j, n}]
```

[image: Sum of ea values]

Comment: Very insightful, thanks!  I shouldn't post questions at 5pm on Friday afternoon ;)

Comment: I know the feeling well (and it can be even worse at 10pm especially for answers).  I wonder if you should be considering correlated normals as opposed to independent normals.

Comment: Good thought, but I think independent normals is appropriate, since the distributions represent separate species' phenotypic distributions.

Answer (score 6):

Include assumptions

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a[xi_, xj_] := E^(-1/2*(xi - xj)^2/σa^2);

Assuming[
  {σa > 0, Element[n, PositiveIntegers]},
  Expectation[Sum[a[x[i], x[j]], {j, n}], 
   x[i] \[Distributed] 
    NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {10.6525, (E^(-((x[j] - xav[i])^2/(2 (σa^2 + σ[i]^2))))
   n σa)/Sqrt[σa^2 + σ[i]^2]} *)
```

Comment: Interesting!  Although 10 seconds is still slower than my manual switch time of 1, and `Method -> "Procedural"` really hurts (500 s!)

Comment: Oops, also not the right answer, since it seems to assume that all `x[j]` are the same!

Comment: You only showed one of the x[j] as random (specifically x[i]). You need to reformulate the problem if all of the x[j] are random.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your last comment before I wrote my comment on the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
sum /: Expectation[sum[a_, b__], c___] := sum[Expectation[a, c], b]

ReplaceAll[sum -> Sum]@
  Block[{Sum = sum}, Expectation[Sum[a[x[i], x[j]], {j, n}, Method -> "Procedural"], 
    x[i] \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[xav[i], σ[i]]]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```